# How to add header to AllItems.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-definition

Wondering if and how this is possible.

I have a Document Library list definition that I use to create several lists.  I want to modify the AllItems.aspx so that there is a header with the lists name at the top

```
<div class="headerStyle">
   (list name)
</div>
```

The final result would be

LIST NAME

Title   Description   Uploaded By  Upload Date

Does someone have an example?  Ideally i would like to do this in Visual Studio and not via SD.

Answer (score 1):

The main scenario to modify list view is to use XSLT. You can create your custom template as describen in [this post](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html). Then you should override main.xsl in your list definition.